# Searchview overlaps custom title in toolbar. How to prevent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, searchview

My toolbar contains :

- my own views at start of the toolbar and
- then a standard iconized searchview, which can be expanded by clicking the search icon:

[image]

When clicking icon to expand the search it overlaps the title:

[image]

How can I achieve to expand the searchview only to the end of "MY TITLE"?

**Main layout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="5dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/myToolbarTheme"
            app:title="">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_title" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_tabs" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ViewFlipper .....
```

**toolbar_title layout:** included in Mainlayout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/current_view_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_view_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_view_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chronology" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appbar_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="MY TITLE"
    android:textColor="@color/navigation_inner_color"
    android:textSize="22dp" />
```

**Inflating menu in code:**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
appToolbar = context.findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity) context).setSupportActionBar(appToolbar);
appToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu);
```

**R.menu.main_menu with quicksearch:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="mypackage.toolbar.ArrayAdapterSearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        android:title="Bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_menuitem_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: did you tried using `android:singleLine="true"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options,

Set width to SearchView in styles

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">140dp</item>
</style>
```

Second option is get SeachView instance in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and calculate width of your `toolbar_title layout` set remaining width to search bar.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
   searchView.setMaxWidth(calculatedWidth);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But as per android standards, Search View has to extend completely in toolbar.
For this we have to use `searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`.